# postgres -c <parameter>=<value> not working for Postgres 11 in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, configuration

I'm running a Postgres inside a docker container. I want to change the default config of Postgres so I'm running:

```
docker container run -d postgres -c max_connections=200 -c shared_buffers=1GB -c effective_cache_size=3GB -c maintenance_work_mem=256MB -c checkpoint_completion_target=0.7 -c wal_buffers=16MB
```

But when I'm connecting to Postgres running:

```
 docker exec -it container_name psql
```

And then the result of :

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

is

```
 max_connections
-----------------
 100
(1 row)
```

And it's not just `max_connections`. None of the parameters are changed. And I don't know what is the problem with what I'm doing?

**Update:** the result of

```
root=# SELECT *
root-# FROM   pg_settings
root-# WHERE  name = 'max_connections';
```

is

```
      name       | setting | unit |                       category                       |                     short_desc                     | extra_desc |  context   | vartype |       source       | min_val | max_val | enumvals | boot_val | reset_val |                sourcefile                | sourceline | pending_restart
-----------------+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+---------+--------------------+---------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------
 max_connections | 100     |      | Connections and Authentication / Connection Settings | Sets the maximum number of concurrent connections. |            | postmaster | integer | configuration file | 1       | 262143  |          | 100      | 100       | /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf |         64 | f
(1 row)
```

Comment: You certainly need to quote any spaces in arguments to `-c`, but my advice is to omit those soaces altogether. If it still doesn't work, perhaps the settings are overridden somewhere else. Examine `pg_settings`.

Comment: It's not wroking without spaces too @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Ok, so what does `pg_settings` tell you about this parameter?

Comment: It says 100 too @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Yes, and what else? It also contains information where the value comes from.

Comment: I added it in question @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: So what you tried had no effect. Maybe the server was already started? Why don't you set the parameters in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: I don't know how to change parameters in postgresql.conf from inside psql @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: I have added a new answer that shows you how you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot get it to work while starting the server, try `ALTER SYSTEM`:

```
psql -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET max_connections=200; SELECT pg_reload_conf()"
```

That changes the setting in `postgresql.auto.conf`.

Changing `shared_buffers`, wal_buffers`and`max_connections` require a restart of the PostgreSQL server, the other parameters can be changed on the fly.

Comment: Restarting docker is the only way to change them?

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are connecting to the wrong container? When I try to run `psql` as you have, I get:

```
$ docker exec -it boring_hermann psql
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

...because the standard user is `root` and has no access to the container's DB. When I run as user 999, group 999 (the one listed as `postgres` in that image), it works correctly:

```
$ docker exec -u 999:999 -it boring_hermann psql
psql (11.1 (Debian 11.1-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# show max_connections;
 max_connections 
-----------------
 200
(1 row)
```

Comment: Sadly not working for me.I did not had a 'postgres' user. I created it and logged in with it. but parameters aren't changed.

Comment: @GoodReads Are you using the standard "postgres" image from Docker Hub?